# ¿Cómo crear archivos a partir de nombres con espacio que están guardados en un archivo?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

¿Cómo puedo crear una carpeta que tenga espacio, pero, por ejemplo leyendo un archivo que tenga los nombres?

ejemplo

```
mkdir carpeta con espacio
```

esto me creará 3 carpetas.

si le pongo "" al nombre me creara solo una. Sin embargo, el problema radica en que estoy leyendo un archivo donde tengo las rutas de esta forma:

```
carpeta/carpeta con espacio/carpeta
carpeta/carpeta/carpeta con espacio
carpeta/carpeta/carpeta/carpeta con espacio
```

Entonces, necesito hacerlo pero a gran escala.

me habian mencionado que si cambio el valor de la variable PS1 quedaria de forma recursiva para el resto de shell que ejecutara. pero nose la verdad como.
el output de

```
echo $PS1
```

es

```
\[\e]0;\u@\h \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\] \[\033[01;34m\]\w \$\[\033[00m\]
```

Comment: `PS1` no tiene nada que ver, es solamente el valor que te aparece en el prompt de la consola. La clave aquí está en las comillas y en usar `mkdir -p` para crear la estructura de directorios, como bien responde alo Malbarez.

Comment: Nótese por cierto que si su respuesta te ayuda, podrías aceptarla (y lo mismo con el resto de preguntas que has formulado). Lee [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

Asumiendo que el nombre de las carpetas está en un archivo `carpetas.txt` :

```
$ while read -r linea; do if [ "$linea" ]; then mkdir -p "$linea"; fi; done < carpetas.txt;
```

1. mientras haya líneas para leer (**-r** evita que el "\" funcione como continuador de línea en el caso de ser el último caracter antes del salto de línea)
2. si no es una línea vacía (daría error)
3. crear carpeta (**-p** crea las carpetas padre)
4. se inyecta el archivo al loop

Comment: ¡Buena respuesta! Podrías usar `[ -n "$linea" ]`, que valida si la longitud de `$linea` es mayor que 0.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar:

1. **xargs**.

   Por ejemplo, para las tres ramas de carpetas que pusiste, puedes ejecutar lo siguiente:

   ```
   $ xargs -I {} mkdir -p {} <<< "$(echo "carpeta/carpeta con espacio/carpeta
   carpeta/carpeta/carpeta con espacio
   carpeta/carpeta/carpeta/carpeta con espacio")"
   ```

   Y el resultado es:

   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

   Pero, si estás leyendo desde un archivo:

   ```
   $ xargs -I {} mkdir -p {} < archivo_rutas
   ```

   Como mencionó @Ole Tange, a diferencia de lo que aparece en la imagen, no son 
   necesarias las comillas en el placeholder.

   En lo personal, me gusta más usar xargs que un bucle común, ya sabes, porque se puede paralelizar, etc.
2. **gnu/parallel**:

   ```
   $ parallel mkdir -p {} ::: "carpeta/carpeta con espacio/carpeta
   carpeta/carpeta/carpeta con espacio
   carpeta/carpeta/carpeta/carpeta con espacio"
   ```

   O leyendo de un archivo:

   ```
   $ parallel mkdir -p {} :::: archivo_rutas
   ```

Comment: " no son necesarios alrededor de {}.

Comment: Tienes razón. Vieja costumbre de ponerle comillas a todo. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

in ssh

ssh -p 8022 u0_a250@192.168.20.25 xargs -I {} mkdir -p {} <<< "$(echo "/sdcard/carpeta con espacio")"

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).